# How to watch input buttons with specified name?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For example I have long list of buttons: `<input type=button name=clickbutton onclick='dosomething(this)'>`

But instead of putting call to the same function in every button it would be more rational to add a single listening event that would wait for click of that button with this name. But again, there are many this buttons so I need pass clicked object to a function. For example this function must update a textarea field that is adjacent (nextSibling) to this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up event delegation. This may be what you need. There are many good resources for it on google.

**Update:**
Sorry, I could have put a little more effort into the answer, Here are some results [Google Search...](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,27814,28055&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=event+delegation&cp=10&qe=ZXZlbnQgZGVsZQ&qesig=YunYqIYViipvFSl8RSGmOQ&pkc=AFgZ2tn_V8paDqd1dWzh9UddWXEIVlus_8r2h6Yl2ZDfGXRH8T-Zlij0I2WTCqZgtry6cgbFlpclnu7T4mPNh491dJiNhPgW3w&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=event+dele&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ca05a7bb65e82229)

You would then use a switch to determine what action you want to take based on the event.name attribute. Cool thing about that approach is if you have a great deal of elements on the page with events, it sounds like you do, it should make your page feel more responsive; as the browser does not have to deal with the extra overhead of on event per element.

Answer (score 3):

You could use jQuery:

```
$('input[name|="clickbutton"]').click(function() {

    var currentButton = $(this);
    alert(currentButton.attr('id'));

});
```

This attaches a click function to all input elements with a name of 'clickbutton'. `currentButton` is the input element that was just clicked. The function then alerts the id of the `currentButton`.

**UPDATE:** I've created a working example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/cdsWk/1/

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName('clickbutton');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
        this.nextSibling.innerHTML = 'clicked!';
    }
```